# Is there a Yahoo Search Service that returns JSON like the Google Search Service?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-search

Looking for the Yahoo equivalent of this

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=SomeQueryString

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

http://search.yahooapis.com/WebSearchService/V1/webSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=madonna&results=2&output=json

Comment: seems like it doesn't work anymore, are there any new ways on how to use it